# How to filter a local hasMany record set in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am having issues making the dom update when filtering a `ul` of hasMany objects. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

When a user clicks on one of the links it should filter down a div containing the respective elements. Here is my current code:

---

### Route

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin,{
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('recipient', params.recipient_id);
  },

  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    var categories = model.get('offers').map(function(offer){
      var category = Ember.Object.create();
      category.name = offer.get('company_industry');
      category.count = model.get('offers').filterBy('company_industry', offer.get('company_industry')).get('length');
      return category;
    });

    controller.set('categories', categories);
  }

});
```

This sets `categories` to an Ember object liks so:
`{name: 'Home And Beauty', count: 1}`

### Component: filterable-offers.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  actions: {
    filter: function(categoryName) {
      return this.get('model').get('offers').filterBy("company_industry", categoryName);
    }
  }

});
```

### filterable-offers.hbs

```
<ul>
  {{#each categories as |category|}}
      <li>
        <a {{action "filter" category.name}}>{{category.name}} ({{category.count}})</a>
      </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

## recipient.hbs

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    {{filterable-offers categories=categories model=model}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    {{#each model.offers as |offer|}}
      <div class="offer-card">
        {{offer.text}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
```

---

I know I'm missing some simple like observing something here, but when I click the link to filter down the elements nothing is updated in the dom. The filter function does return the result set I want but it isn't being observed by the `model.offers` call in the main recipient template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're returning your filtered result from your action handler. The action handler doesn't use a return value (for the most part). Instead, you need to place your filtered items somewhere where your template can access them. Since your filter selector is in a different component, this is what I would do (if you have questions about any part of this, just ask):

1. In your component, re-send the filter action so it bubbles to the controller:

   ```
   actions: {
       filter(categoryName) {
           this.sendAction('filterByCategory', categoryName);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make sure your controller can receive the action by subscribing to it in the template:

   ```
   {{filterable-offers categories=categories filterByCategory='filterByCategory'}}
   ```
3. Add a handler for the `filterByCategory` action in your controller:

   ```
   actions: {
       filterByCategory(categoryName) {
           // We'll use this in the next step
           this.set('filterCategory', categoryName);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Set up a computed property that will automatically filter your items based on the filter category. We have our `filterCategory` property on the controller, so let's use that:

   ```
   filteredOffers: Ember.computed('model.offers.@each.company_industry', 'filterCategory', {
       get() {
           const offers = this.get('model.offers');
           const filterCategory = this.get('filterCategory');

           // If there's no category to filter by, return all of the offers
           if (filterCategory) {
               return offers.filterBy('company_industry', filterCategory);
           } else {
               return offers;
           }
       }
   })
   ```
5. Finally, instead of using `model.offers` in your template, use `filteredOffers`

   ```
       {{#each filteredOffers as |offer|}} ... {{/each}}
   ```

That answer might be a tad more in-depth than you want, but hopefully it helps. The major sticking point you were having is that you needed some way to tell your controller to use a filtered set of offers instead of the original set. This is just one of many ways to accomplish that.

Comment: super helpful answer. One question I have for you. When ember 2.0 comes and controllers begin to be deprecated, how would your answer change? No need to spend much time with this question as you have already exceeded my expectations, just a thought.

Comment: My answer specifically won't change. You'll still do all of the same things. But instead of putting `filterByCategory` action in the controller you'll put it in your routable component. The code will remain the same though.

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of the `get()` function call is for inside the controller?

Comment: That's the [new computed property syntax](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/05/13/ember-1-12-released.html#toc_new-computed-syntax) introduced in 1.12. I also used quite a few ES6 features (since Ember CLI includes Babel by default), so if you see something you don't recognize, maybe give the ES6 feature set another read through. :)